# How to send a serializable object of external library through sockets?

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization

I have a simple class library which contains only one type. Now I want to send an instance of this type from client to server by using sockets. A client and a server know nothing about SendingObject type that why I need to load assembly.

```
[Serializable]
    public class SendingObject : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public SendingObject() { }

        public SendingObject(string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            FirstName = firstname;
            LastName = lastname;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format($"Firstname: {FirstName}. Lastname: {LastName}.");
        }
    }
```

This is a code of my **client**:

```
   class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {   
                string path = @"path to MyLibrary.dll";
                Assembly library = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);

                Type typeObj = library.GetType("MyLibrary.SendingObject");
                var sob = Activator.CreateInstance(typeObj, new object[] {"Bob", "Smith"});

                try
                {
                    SendAddUserMessageFromSocket(83, sob);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\nTap to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }

            static void SendAddUserMessageFromSocket(int port, object obj)
            {    
                byte[] brr = ObjectToByteArray(obj);

                IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
                IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[0];
                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

                Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                sender.Connect(endPoint);

                NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(sender);

                if (networkStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    networkStream.Write(brr, 0, brr.Length);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("The message was sent.");
            }

            // Convert an object to a byte array
            private static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                    return null;

                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

                return ms.ToArray();
            }

            // Convert a byte array to an Object
            private static Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
            {
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
                memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);

                return obj;
            }
        }
```

This recevied object will be deserialize on a server side. This is a code of my server.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 83);
            Socket socketListener = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            string path = @"path to MyLibrary.dll";
            Assembly library = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
            Type typeObj = library.GetType("MyLibrary.SendingObject");

            try
            {
                socketListener.Bind(endPoint);
                socketListener.Listen(10);
                bool isWorkFinished = false;

                while (!isWorkFinished)
                {
                    Socket handler = socketListener.Accept();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[2064];

                    // Get data from connected socket to buffer
                    int numberOfReceivedBytes = handler.Receive(bytes);

                    byte[] bytesObject = new byte[numberOfReceivedBytes];

                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReceivedBytes; i++)
                        bytesObject[i] = bytes[i];

                    object res = ByteArrayToObject(bytesObject);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nTap to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        // Convert an object to a byte array
        private static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        // Convert a byte array to an Object
        private static Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);

            return obj;
        }
    }
```

My SendingObject can be serialize, but I have an error trying to deserialize it.

> The assembly can't be found:"MyLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

Comment: 2 things. Both projects have to use the same serialization and deserialization library ( eg.Me.Packet.Deserializer.dll ) both of the projects have to use the same version of external library. Is that what you currently have?

Comment: This is indeed what you get if you don't reference a common interface DLL from both projects. PS: I'd refrain from using sockets and serialization for things like this; WCF does all this quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so basic things binary serialization within .NET signs out those binary files with some informations like `Type`, `Assembly` etc. That's why for a beginner it would be easier to make library used to serialize data that will hold up references to all objects. example here:

```
// assume this is Me.Serialization.Library.csproj
public class MeSerializer {
    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj){
        // serialization method
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] buffer) {
        // deserialization method
    }
}
```

Now in other two projects (let's say client and server) you just use methods from `Me.Serialization.Library` like :

```
static void SendAddUserMessageFromSocket(int port, object obj)
{    
    // simple edit :
    string path = @"path to MyLibrary.dll";
    Assembly library = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);

    Type typeObj = library.GetType("MyLibrary.SendingObject")
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Me.Serialization.Library.MeSerializer).GetMethod("Serialize");
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeObj);
    byte[] brr = (byte[])generic.Invoke(null, obj); // null because it is static

    // remember to add reference to Me.Serialization.Library
    // byte[] brr = Me.Serialization.Library.MeSerializer.Serialize<MyLibrary.SendingObject>(obj);

    IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[0];
    // skipped rest of the code for readability
}
```

And do the same in another project :

```
// simple edit :
string path = @"path to MyLibrary.dll";
Assembly library = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);

Type typeObj = library.GetType("MyLibrary.SendingObject")
MethodInfo method = typeof(Me.Serialization.Library.MeSerializer).GetMethod("Deserialize");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeObj);

// remember to add reference to Me.Serialization.Library
while (!isWorkFinished)
{
    Socket handler = socketListener.Accept();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2064];

    // Get data from connected socket to buffer
    int numberOfReceivedBytes = handler.Receive(bytes);

    byte[] bytesObject = new byte[numberOfReceivedBytes];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReceivedBytes; i++)
        bytesObject[i] = bytes[i];

    object brr = (object)generic.Invoke(null, bytesObject);
    // object res = (object)Me.Serialization.Library.MeSerializer.Deserialize<MeLibrary.SendingObject>(bytesObject);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have no the type of `SendingObject`. That why I get it from the loaded assembly: `Assembly library = Assembly.LoadFrom(path); Type typeObj = library.GetType("MyLibrary.SendingObject");` I can't use this variable as generic parameter for `Serialize <T>` method.

Comment: Oh, but that's not a problem. I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. `Serialize<MyLibrary.SendingObject>` I have no any refrences to `MyLibrary`. I have only `Me.Serialization.Library` (it hasn't any reference inside). How can I set generic parameter to `Serialize` method?

Comment: As I said look at my edited answer. This should work okay. But if not just let me know in the comment.

Comment: Is it works for you? I got and exception in `Deserialize` method. The assembly can't be found:"MyLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".